# Getting OCIError: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes From Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle, activerecord, georuby

Here is the scenario.
I'm writing my geo-ruby oracle adapter for Ruby On Rails which supports working with SDO_GEOMETRY out of box.
It was going well. I wrote codes for selecting SDO_GEOMETRY objects from Oracle DB successfully.
Everything ruins up when I wanted to write insert and update parts.
Following is what's in my mind. I want to be able to do this statement:

```
g = GeoShape.new(name:"point1", shape: Point.from_x_y(-34,-43,4326))
g.save
```

I generated following sql query from the above statements:

```
INSERT INTO "GEO_SHAPES" ("CREATED_AT", "ID", "NAME", "SHAPE", "UPDATED_AT") VALUES (:a1, :a2, :a3, :a4, :a5)  [["created_at", Tue, 03 Jul 2012 08:42:01 UTC +00:00], ["id", 10112], ["name", "point1"], ["shape", "SDO_GEOMETRY(2001,  NULL, NULL, SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,1,1), SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(-34,-43))"], ["updated_at", Tue, 03 Jul 2012 08:42:01 UTC +00:00]]
```

But execution of above query gave me this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: OCIError: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY got CHAR
```

I got into oracle_enhanced_adapter to trace the problem. I tried to monkey patch it and  manually initialize binds[3][1] (which is the value of sdo_geometry column in my DB) as follows:

```
    def exec_insert(sql, name, binds)
    log(sql, name, binds) do
      returning_id_index = nil
      cursor = if @statements.key?(sql)
        @statements[sql]
      else
        @statements[sql] = @connection.prepare(sql)
      end

    binds[3][1] = "SDO_GEOMETRY(2001,  NULL, NULL, SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,1,1), SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(-34,-43))" ### DAVE

      binds.each_with_index do |bind, i|
        col, val = bind
        if col == :returning_id
          returning_id_index = i + 1
          cursor.bind_returning_param(returning_id_index, Integer)
        else
          if val == "SDO_GEOMETRY(2001,  NULL, NULL, SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,1,1), SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(-34,-43))" ### DAVE
            cursor.bind_param(i + 1, val, OCI8::Object::Mdsys::SdoGeometry) ###DAVE
          else ### DAVE
            cursor.bind_param(i + 1, type_cast(val, col), col && col.type)
          end
        end
      end

      cursor.exec_update
```

Unfortunately, it didn't help. I still got the same error ORA-00932.
Any ideas? It's so critical for me to fix this.

P.S: ###DAVE parts are my monkey patches of oracle_enhanced_adapter.rb
P.S: Here is my config.

- Oracle 11.2
- Ruby version              1.9.3 (i386-darwin11.3.0)
- Rails version             3.2.5
- Active Record version     3.2.5

Comment: Have you published this anywhere? I'm looking for a way to insert SDO_GEOMETRY objects directly from ruby using oci8 and your question is the closest thing I've seen to someone else trying to do the same.

Comment: Yes, you can find my forked version of oracle enhanced adapter at https://github.com/daqo/oracle-enhanced

Comment: @Jamie Cook
You must change the hardcoded part in oracle_enhanced_adapter.rb.
Just search for OCI8.new,
you will find two instance, change the username, password and database in these two instances. 
If you have any questions and problems in using the fork, feel free to ask; I would be glad to help you.

Comment: Also, have in mind to add required information to user_sdo_geom_metadata.
it's required for the gem to work correctly.

Comment: @JamieCook I removed hardcoded parts. Now you can use Gem freely.

Comment: @DaveQorashi I am using your fork of oracle enhanced adapter. So, can you give me a example of how to right a migration script ? say i want a table called as LocationDevice where point will specify my device (latitude,longitude).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I managed to fix the problem.
Enhanced adapter uses bind_param method to perform binding variables to their appropriate oracle types. Here was the problem and error.
I had to override some codes in oracle_enhanced_adpter.rb.
I add a method to this file to manually build a SDO_GEOMETRY object.
Then I bind this returned object to OCI8::Object::Mdsys::SdoGeometry type.

My method contains these codes (Now, only for creating SDO_GEOMETRY Points):

```
#I needed a connection to my oracle database. Connection placeholder is conn.
def create_sdo_geometry_object(conn, gtype, srid, point, x, y)
    local_cursor = conn.parse("BEGIN :geom := SDO_GEOMETRY(:sdo_gtype, :sdo_srid, :sdo_point, :sdo_elem_info_array, :sdo_ordinate_array); END;")
    local_cursor.bind_param(:sdo_gtype, OraNumber)
    local_cursor.bind_param(:sdo_srid, OraNumber) 
    local_cursor.bind_param(:sdo_point, OCI8::Object::Mdsys::SdoPointType) 
    local_cursor.bind_param(:sdo_elem_info_array, OCI8::Object::Mdsys::SdoElemInfoArray)
    local_cursor.bind_param(:sdo_ordinate_array, OCI8::Object::Mdsys::SdoOrdinateArray)

    local_cursor.bind_param(:geom, OCI8::Object::Mdsys::SdoGeometry)

    sdo_gtype = OraNumber.new(gtype)
    sdo_srid = OraNumber.new(srid)
    sdo_point = nil #Temporarily I set it to nil


    #sdo_elem_info_array must be [1,1,1] for creating points.
    sdo_elem_info_array = OCI8::Object::Mdsys::SdoElemInfoArray.new(conn,OraNumber.new(1),OraNumber.new(1),OraNumber.new(1))
    #I want to create a point with x and y coordinates
    sdo_ordinate_array = OCI8::Object::Mdsys::SdoOrdinateArray.new(conn,OraNumber.new(x),OraNumber.new(y))

    local_cursor[:sdo_gtype] = sdo_gtype
    local_cursor[:sdo_srid] = sdo_srid
    local_cursor[:sdo_point] = sdo_point
    local_cursor[:sdo_elem_info_array] = sdo_elem_info_array
    local_cursor[:sdo_ordinate_array] = sdo_ordinate_array
    local_cursor.exec

    local_cursor[:geom]
end
```

Then when I wanted to bind this parameter I used the following code:

```
cursor.bind_param(i + 1, create_sdo_geometry_object("PARAMS HERE"), OCI8::Object::Mdsys::SdoGeometry)
```

It worked like a charm!